# Adding a key for Android in Phonegap Build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I built an app using Eclipse about a year ago and am trying to release a new version. I built the new version of the Android application using Adobe Build and tested the app.
Everything is working properly in that regard. Then when I go to `Edit Account -> Signing Keys -> Add Key` for my android application, I select the key that I created for my app when it was first released using the correct alias and hit "**submit key**". Once I submit my key the page shows that the key is uploading, however it just continues to load and never completes. I have tried this several times and can't figure out where I am going wrong.

[image]

Comment: Maybe your key expirated (tough the recomended is 25 years)? I would suggest you to contact Adobe.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I had it set for 50 years. The strange thing is that there is no indication of an error, the page just keeps indicating that it is loading. Even if I upload a random file type (e.g. .jpg) rather than a key, no errors are displayed. I left a question on the Phonegap support page but don't know where else to turn for a solution.

Comment: Generate a new key and try that. You only need one key for all your android apps anyway.

Comment: I generated a new key but because I was updating a previous app I needed to use the same key. I solved the issue. When I used eclipse to generate my key, for some reason it didn't end in .keystore. I manually added this to my key file and the upload process worked. Still Adobe doesn't display any errors if there is anything wrong with the file you are uploading which is a pain.